# What are the number of different binary strings of length $n$ which contain a given substring?

Tags: combinatorics

> What are the number of different binary strings of length $n$ which contain a given substring?

For example consider `n = 3` and the substring to be `11`, then there could be `111`, `110`, `011`.

It is easy for small numbers, but as they get larger; it gets more complex. Also, there would also be overlapping cases which will need to be subtracted. Therefore, I think it would use Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: Does anything matter other than the number of bits in the small and larger string? Suppose we find out how many binary strings of length $12$ contain the string $111$ at least once. Then will not exactly the same number of binary strings of length $12$ contain the string $101$? For each larger string that contained $111$ at least once, change the matching substring $111$ to $101$ and you have a $12$ bit string matching $101$, so the number of matching strings would be the same. This would be true of all three bit strings. This simplifies a computer approach since one only has to count $111$etc

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I didn't understand what you mean. Also, no, the number of strings which contain $111$ and $101$ would not be equal because there is a difference in the number of $1$'s and $0$'s. If it were to be $111$ and $000$ then that would be an entirely different thing.

Comment: Is there a flaw in my argument?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Consider the simpler case of strings of length 3 with the substrings $11$ or $10$. For the former, there are $111, 110, 011$ as OP pointed out. For the latter, there are $100, 101, 010, 110$. The difference comes from the fact that prepending and appending a $1$ to $11$ results in the same string, while this is not true for $10$.

Comment: Yes, now I see the flaw in my argument. The procedure I suggested could produce duplicate strings thus increasing the count and it could also undercount by not moving beyond to subsequent matches.